Error on libvips library when installing Ruby on Rails 7.0 app in RHEL8
Trying to install a Ruby on Rails app that uses Rails 7+. Get this error:
Could not open library 'vips.so.42': vips.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libvips.so.42': libvips.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
when running rake secret, but appears to be a much larger issue. Rails 7+ has switched to using libvips over imagemagick, and this application was coded to use libvips over it, so I can't just change it with the option:
config.active_storage.variant_processor = :mini_magick
instead of
config.active_storage.variant_processor = :vips
I'm trying to do this on RHEL8, which seemingly has no package repositories for libvips and its large amount of dependencies. I found this strange
I've tried to use snapd to install the libvips snap, had no change though seemed successful but the snap is pretty old. I've tried to compile from source, but sourcing all of the dependencies has proved very challenging.
Has anyone successfully used a Rails 7+ app with libvips on RHEL8/CentOS?

libvips is available in Remi Collet's RPM repository:
https://rpms.remirepo.net/
Kleis Auke wrote some notes on using Remi's rpms in RHEL9 which you should be able to adapt:
https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/356#issuecomment-1287872830
Notes for rhel9:
# Install the EPEL repository configuration package
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

# Enable the CodeReady Builder repository since EPEL packages may depend on packages from it
crb enable
# or:
# subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-$(arch)-rpms

# Install the Remi repository configuration package
dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-9.rpm

# Enable Remi's RPM repository
dnf config-manager --set-enabled remi

# Install libvips (+ development files and command-line tools)
dnf install vips vips-devel vips-tools

## Install optional modules
## See: https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/171

# HEIC / AVIF support via libheif
dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-9.noarch.rpm
dnf install vips-heif

# JPEG-XL support via libjxl
dnf install vips-jxl

# *Magick support via GraphicsMagick
dnf install vips-magick-gm

# *Magick support via ImageMagick 6
dnf install vips-magick-im6

# *Magick support via ImageMagick 7
dnf install vips-magick-im7

# OpenSlide support
dnf install vips-openslide

# PDF load support via Poppler
dnf install vips-poppler


This repo got me what I needed for RHEL8- Thanks!
